# Nature of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find the sequence $x_n$ if i have given $f$ a real function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x)= \arcsin(\sin x)$, $x_0 = 2003, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $n \geq 1,$ we have  $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$?

I have to study the nature of that sequence and I know how to do that part but I have no idea how can i found that sequence $x_n$, i am not sure if I can use the approximation method to find it because it is not numerical analysis problem, I only need a start idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Prove $\sin\arcsin x=x$ for $|x|\le1$. Hence prove $f$ is idempotent.

Comment: Just notice that for every $x_n$, including $x_0$, $|\sin x_n| \leqslant 1 $, so that $x_1, x_2, \cdots  \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] $ and $ \arcsin(\sin x_n) = x_n$.

Comment: Looking at the graph $arcsin(sinx)$ might give you a starting idea.

Comment: I got it, thank you all for your kind replies.